# Command "docker-compose up" results in "command not found : no mount point specified" error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-image

I am trying to modify an Expressvpn container I found online. I cloned the repository to create my own modified image from it. I have spend all day trying to create a new image without modifying the existing code.

All I did was add a docker-compose.yml file to the directory as specified on the Github page:

```
---
version: "2.1"
services:
    expressvpn_test:
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: expressvpn_test
        environment:
          - ACTIVATION_CODE={% your-activation-code %}
        cap_add:
          - NET_ADMIN
        devices: 
          - /dev/net/tun
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
        command: /bin/bash
        privileged: true
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - 80:80 # example
```

When I run the command "docker-compose up" in the directory of the repository I get the following error:

```
/tmp/entrypoint.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
: no mount point specified.
cp: cannot stat '/tmp/resolv.conf': No such file or directory
/etc/init.d/expressvpn: line 207: log_action_msg: command not found
": no such file or directoryressvpnActivate.sh
Cannot connect to expressvpnd daemon.
It seems that the expressvpn daemon is not running. Please run "sudo service expressvpn restart" to 
start it.
If the problem persists, please contact us.
: No such file or directory /bin/bash
```

If I pull the original image and run it there are no problems. I am new to Docker and I can't seem to figure out how I can solve this.

I hope someone can help me out with this problem.

Comment: `\r: command not found` almost always means you're building on a Windows system but forgot to convert your files to Unix line endings.

Comment: That has indeed solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)